# Scanf: detect that the input was too long

Tags: c, input, scanf

We can easily limit the length of the input accepted by scanf:

```
char str[101];
scanf("%100s", str);
```

Is there any efficient way to find out that the string was trimmed? We could, for example, report an error in such case.

We could read `"%101s"` into `char strx[102]` and check with `strlen()` but this involves extra cost.

Comment: `"%101s"` would be off by one, don;t even try.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, of course into **another** array, longer. Added this to clarify

Comment: By using `fgets` instead, and making sure the input string ends with a newline (or if from a file, is at EOF). If not, then it was trimmed.

Comment: The _cost_ of `strlen()` is insignificant to `scanf("%100s", str);`.  If still want to find the length, use `scanf("%100s%n", str, &length);`

Comment: If You are about microseconds cost, dont use scanf at all. Any method withou parser wiil be better

Comment: @JacekCz: Actually a parser would make things faster and allow for such detection OP asks for. `scanf` is not really a parser.

Comment: @JacekCz  Note that `scanf("%100s", str);` may or may not be faster than another input function.  An optimizing compiler will "see" inside `scanf("%100s", ...` and possible generate very efficient code.

Comment: How is your code going to react if the input is too long?  If it is exactly long enough?  Do you have just the one blank-less field on the line, or are there other fields on the line?  Does your code have more than one conversion specification in the format string or is it exactly as shown?  Could there be other data on the line after this field?  How your code will react strongly influences what can/should do about overlong fields.  Are you not going to need to know how long the string is anyway?  If you are, then checking the length isn't a big problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `%n` conversion to write the scan position to an integer. If it was 100 past the beginning then the string was too big.

I find that `%n` is useful for all kinds of things.

I thought the above was plenty of information for anyone who had read the `scanf` docs / man page and had actually *tried it*.

The idea is that you make your buffer and your scan limit bigger than whatever size string you *expect* to find. Then if you find a scan result that is exactly as big as your scan limit you know it is an invalid string. Then you report an error or exit or whatever it is that you do.

Also, if you're about to say "But I want to report an error and continue on the next line but scanf left my file in an unknown position."
That is why you read a line at a time using `fgets` and then use `sscanf` instead of `scanf`. It removes the possibility of ending the scan in the middle of the line and makes it easy to count line numbers for error reporting.

So here is the code that I just wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int scan_input(const char *input) {
        char buf[101];
        int position = 0;
        int matches = sscanf(input, "%100s%n", buf, &position);
        printf("'%s' matches=%d position=%d\n", buf, matches, position);
        if (matches < 1)
                return 2;
        if (position >= 100)
                return 3;
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if (argc < 2)
                exit(1);
        const char *input = argv[1];
        return scan_input(input);
}
```

And here is what happens:

> $ ./a.out 'This is a test string'
>   'This' matches=1 position=4
>   $ ./a.out 'This-is-a-test-string'
>   'This-is-a-test-string' matches=1 position=21
>   $ ./a.out '01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
>   '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789' matches=1 position=100

Comment: As I see it, _"The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
signed integer into which is to be written the number of characters read from
the input stream so far by this call"_, how will this ever be more than the max width, whatever be the actual input? Can you please elaborate what am I missing?

Comment: I can't see how %n helps you distinguishing from an input that was too long from an input that fits exactly. Could you please include an example?

Comment: `%n` is a good starting idea ,yet "If it was 100 past" needs explaining.  I do not see how "it"` will be past 100.

Comment: I guess an example could sort some of the doubts out

Comment: @ZanLynx by "fits exactly" I mean it fits in the array with just enough room for the null-terminator. `%n` gives you `100` when you type 100 characters (which is correct) and  *also gives you `100`* when you type **more** than 100 characters. So it doesn't help distincting normal from abnormal usage.

Comment: It's not about the length of the buffer. It's about knowing if the user typed 100 characters or more than 100 characters, and `%n` doesn't help you with that.

Comment: First, take it easy; no need for CAPS. Second, you are misunderstanding the issue entirely. Please just go ahead and try to write a small program that does what OP asked. You'll realize it's not possible to do it properly with `%n`.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean now. It's exactly what OP suggested but without strlen(). Alright, makes sense. I have edited the answer to include the code segment we requested. Please take a look and edit it as you wish to make sure that this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Minor: `scan_input("");` leads to UB as code attempt to print `buf[]` which is not initialized nor assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the code. No need to be passive-aggressive about it though. I really tried to understand your answer. And I did try to write my own piece of code using `%n`. The reason I failed is because I was thinking of the code posted by the author, where in `%100n` the `100` was chosen specifically to be one byte shorter than `char[101]`. So when you suggested to use a 200-char array I thought of modifying `scanf()` to `%199s`. You'll probably agree tht `%n` doesn't help this way. Next time, please, just show the code.

Comment: But this doesn't distinguish between a situation when 100 or 101 characters were provided by the user. And in our case, providing 100 characters is valid.

Comment: @marmistrz: Paragraph FOUR.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `fgets()` to read an entire line. Then you verify if the newline character is in the string. However, this has a few disadvantages:

1. It will consume the entire line, and maybe that's not what you want. Notice that `fgets()` is not equivalent to `scanf("%100s")` -- the latter only reads until the first blank character appears;
2. If the input stream is closed before a newline character is supplied, you will be undecided;
3. You have to go through the array to search for the newline character.

So the better option seems to be as such:

```
char str[101];
int c;
scanf("%100s", str);
c = getchar();
ungetc(c, stdin);
if (c == EOF || isspace(c)) {
    /* successfuly read everything */
}
else {
    /* input was too long */
}
```

This reads the string normally and checks for the next character. If it's a blank or if the stream has been closed, then everything was read.

The `ungetc()` is there in case you don't want your test to modify the input stream. But it's probably unnecessary.

Comment: Note that `ungetc(EOF, stdin);` has specified behavior.  The `if (c != EOF)` is not needed AFAICT.

Comment: That would be nice. But are you sure? The manpages don't say anything about that case.

Comment: The C spec provides defined behavior 'If the value of c equals that of the macro `EOF`, the operation fails and the input stream is unchanged."   C11 §7.21.7.10 4

Comment: After scanning in characters, `"%100s"` stops on any white-space vs "blank".  You may want to review and consider  `isspace(c)` vs. `isblank(c)`

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` is a better way to go, read the line of user input and then parse it.

But is OP still wants to use `scanf()`....

Since it is not  possible to "detect that the input was too long" without attempting to read more than the `n` maximum characters, code needs to read beyond.

```
unsigned char sentinel;
char str[101];
str[0] = '\0';

if (scanf("%100s%c", str, &sentinel) == 2) {
  ungetc(sentential, stdin);  // put back for next input function
  if (isspace(sentential) NoTrimOccurred();
  else TrimOccurred();
 else {
   NoTrimOccurred();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A very rough but easy way of doing this would be, adding a `getchar()` call after the `scanf()`.

`scanf()` leaves the `newline` into the input buffer after reading the actual input. In case, the supplied input is *less* than the maximum field width, `getchar()` would return the newline. Otherwise, the first *unconsumed* input will be returned.

That said, the ideal way of doing it is to *actually* read a bit more than the *required* value and see if anything appears in the *buffer* area. You can make use of `fgets()` and then, check for the `100`th element value to be a `newline` or not but this also comes with *additional cost*.

Comment: And what if we'd like to detect that in `scanf("%100s %d")`?